# How do I add an external .js file to my index.html? (VueJS2)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

So I have two external Javascript files for handling the animations and triangulation of vectors for a background animation. Now, in a normal html/css/js project I would just include those two `.js` files in a `<script src="fileLoc.."></script>`
before the end of the `</body>` tag in my regular `index.html` file.
My question is, how do I include those two `.js` files into my VueJS2 project's `index.html` file? Just puttin `<script>` tags before the `</body>` end does absolutely nothing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share those files cdn ?

Comment: @C2486 I don't have them as cdn, only a location in the file hierarchy which would be `'./src/assets/delaunay.js'` and `'./src/assets/bg.js'` if you mean that

Comment: are you using webpack ?

Comment: @r3zaxd1 Yes I am

Comment: You should use externals : https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: Are you using `vue-cli` by chance?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Yes I'm using vue-cli. Why?
@r3zaxd1 I've looked into the documentation but dont quite get how they extract "jQuery"  `externals: {jquery: 'jQuery'}`
from the file. All I saw when looking into the jQuery file was a `var jQuery` that required jQuery. It's kinda confusing, I'm not sure what's going on or how I can apply externals like that with my files.
And I'm sorry for all the newb questions but I learned Vue yesterday up to dealing with the router and I never before programmed so to say in JS, just dealt with jQuery animations.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `entry` point and give it a name using `webpack chain` in your `vue.config.js`. This will automagically be inserted in your `index.html` file:

```
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config
      .entry('delaunay')
      .add('src/assets/delaunay.js')
      .end()
  }
}
```

This should work for you in practice.

Comment: I've done that without doing anything in externals by creating a vue.config.js file in root and instead of delaunay, i've created a hello.js with an alert inside it. But, nothing got inserted into the index.html

Answer (score 0):

in your js file you can do this:

```
import delaunay from './src/assets/delaunay.js'
import bg from './src/assets/bg.js'
```